# Moment isSameOrAfter not calculating correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, momentjs

Not sure if I have the correct parameters, syntax, or am just flat out not using it correctly but when using `isSameOrAfter` while checking if a current utc date time is after a date is coming back false when it should be true.

```js
var utcDateTime = "8/28/2018 7:30:00 PM";
var oneDayBefore = moment(utcDateTime, "M/D/YYYY h:mm:ss A").subtract(1, 'days');

// oneDayBefore should now be 8/27/2018 7:30:00 PM
if (moment().utc().isSameOrAfter(oneDayBefore, 'day')) {
  alert('is same or after')
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE**

> I think I fixed it, but please advise if this is the best way of
> checking whether the current utc moment date time is the same or after
> one that I've passed in - 1 day

```
moment().utcOffset((moment().utcOffset() * -1)).isSameOrAfter(oneDayBefore, 'day')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found two ways to do it but please advise, I'm a little confused about the parameters of days', 'minutes', etc that can be put into the method

```js
var utcDateTime = "8/28/2018 7:30:00 PM";
var oneDayBefore = moment(utcDateTime, "M/D/YYYY h:mm:ss A").subtract(1, 'days');
var currentUtcMoment = moment().utc().format("M/D/YYYY h:mm:ss A");

if (moment(currentUtcMoment).isSameOrAfter(oneDayBefore, 'day')) {
  // do something
}
```

or

```js
var utcDateTime = "8/28/2018 7:30:00 PM";
var oneDayBefore = moment(utcDateTime, "M/D/YYYY h:mm:ss A").subtract(1, 'days');
var currentUtcMoment = moment().utc().format("M/D/YYYY h:mm:ss A");

if (moment().utcOffset((moment().utcOffset() * -1)).isSameOrAfter(oneDayBefore, 'day')) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a timezone issue. Your `oneDayBefore` is using the default local timezone:

```
var oneDayBefore = moment(utcDateTime, "M/D/YYYY h:mm:ss A").subtract(1, 'days');
```

whereas the moment you're comparing it to is using UTC:

```
moment().utc().isSameOrAfter(oneDayBefore, 'day')
//      ^^^^^^
```

The problem will be clearer if you check the `.format()` of each one. For example, in my time zone (CST), I see:

```js
const utcDateTime = "8/28/2018 7:30:00 PM";
const oneDayBefore = moment(utcDateTime, "M/D/YYYY h:mm:ss A").subtract(1, 'days');
console.log(oneDayBefore.format());

// 2018-08-27T19:30:00-05:00
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

In my time zone, UTC midnight is at 19:00, local time. So, 19:30 local time actually corresponds to 00:30 *the next day* UTC time.

Thus, when you call

```
moment().utc().isSameOrAfter
```

that's comparing the current UTC time/day against whatever time your `"8/28 7:30:00 PM"` minus one day corresponds to *in local time*. But, 8/27 7:30 PM local time may be 8/28 in UTC time - hence, you're comparing `moment().utc()` (at time of writing, 8/27 23:45) against 8/28 00:30 (or something similar - it depends on your timezone).

It's probably best to use UTC time internally as much as possible, and only format it when it needs to be displayed to the user. That is, instead of calling

```
moment(utcDateTime...
```

call

```
moment.UTC(utcDateTime...
```

and the results will be as expected:

```js
const utcDateTime = "8/28/2018 7:30:00 PM";
const oneDayBefore = moment.utc(utcDateTime, "M/D/YYYY h:mm:ss A").subtract(1, 'days');
//                         ^^^^
console.log(oneDayBefore.format());
const now = moment.utc();
console.log(now.format());


console.log(now.isSameOrAfter(oneDayBefore, 'day'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```